# Удалить оси у Chart

Tags: c#, диаграммы

Как сделать так, чтобы оси *x* и *y* не отображались на графике *Chart*?

Answer (score 2):

С помощью свойства Enabled осей.

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
...
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
```